# Problemas de incompatibilidad de diseño y ejecucion de reproductor de audio en navegadores

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un pequeño problema de diseño y ejecución del reproductor de audio. Mayormente la codificación se realizó para Firefox, pero en Chrome no se reproduce, tampoco el diseño, el cual se pierde.

**Código**

```js
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'audio.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = false;
audio.autoplay = true;

var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);

function initMp3Player() {
  document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
  context = new AudioContext();
  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  frameLooper();
}

function frameLooper() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
  fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
  bars = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
    bar_x = i * 3;
    bar_width = 2;
    bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 5);

    ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#mp3_player {
  float: left;
  width: 290px;
  height: 65px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

div#mp3_player>div>audio {
  width: 270px;
  background: #000;
  float: left;
}

div#mp3_player>canvas {
  width: 270px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #002D3C;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!--Hoja y script del reproductor audio-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="audio.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="audio.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mp3_player">
    <div id="audio_box"></div>
    <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

La parte:

```
context = new webkitAudioContext();
```

se cambió a:

```
context = new AudioContext();
```

pero aun así no funciona. También sucede en los dispositivos móviles usando Chrome.

- ¿Cuál sería la solución en los navegadores de sobremesa y dispositivos móviles?.
- Aparte del formato MP3, ¿cómo integraría otros formatos OGG y WAV?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El diseño no tiene problemas. Es normal que dependiendo del navegador veas uno diseño predeterminado u otro; cada navegador implementa estilos propios por defecto, no es ningún problema de diseño. Si quieres un diseño uniforme puedes ocultar el reproductor por defecto y crear uno. En tu código no veo nada extraño, estás creando un `AudioSourceNode` a partir del elemento audio. Quizás se deba a un conflicto con código de terceros o que no está cargando correctamente las pistas.

Te voy a poner un ejemplo que ilustra tanto el diseño como el funcionamiento (básico, por cuestiones de tiempo):

```js
const context = new AudioContext();
const sourceBuffer = context.createBufferSource();
const songs = new Map();
songs.set('Deadpool\'s song', 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xti25272jspem2h/deadpool%20music%20video.mp3');
const songsIterator = songs[Symbol.iterator]();
const btnPlayPause = document.getElementById('play-pause-btn');
const songName = document.getElementById('song-name');
const progressbar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
let trackStarted = false;

btnPlayPause.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!trackStarted) {
    loadSong((name) => {
      // coloca en pantalla el nombre de la canción
      songName.textContent = name;
      play();
      trackStarted = true;
    });
  }
  
  else if (context.state === 'suspended') {
    resume();
  }
  
  else if (context.state === 'running') {
    pause();
  }
});

sourceBuffer.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  btnPlayPause.querySelector('i').textContent = 'play_arrow';
  trackStart = false;
  console.info('Song ended. No more tracks');
});

function loop(timestamp) {
  const trackDuration = sourceBuffer.buffer.duration * 1000;
  const px = progressbar.offsetWidth;
  const width = Number(progress.style.width.replace(/px/, ''));
  const grow = (px * timestamp) / trackDuration;
  progress.style.width = grow + 'px';

  if (timestamp < trackDuration) {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
}

function play() {
  // conecta el buffer al destino (salida de audio)
  sourceBuffer.connect(context.destination);
  // empieza a tocar la pista
  sourceBuffer.start(context.currentTime);
  btnPlayPause.querySelector('i').textContent = 'pause';
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function pause() {
  context.suspend();
  btnPlayPause.querySelector('i').textContent = 'play_arrow';
}

function resume() {
  context.resume();
  btnPlayPause.querySelector('i').textContent = 'pause';
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function loadSong(cb) {
  const song = songsIterator.next().value;
  const songName = song[0];
  const songURL = song[1];
  
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', songURL);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = () => {
    const data = xhr.response;
    context.decodeAudioData(data, buffer => {
      sourceBuffer.buffer = buffer;
      cb(songName);
    });
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rationale');

.player {
  background-color: #313131;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 350px;
}

.screen {
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.screen #song-name {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  font-family: 'Rationale';
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #888;
  display: flex;
  height: 8px;
}

.progress-bar #progress {
  background-color: #16a085;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width .25s ease;
  width: 0%;
}

.control {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

.control button {
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.control button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.control #play-pause-btn {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 40px;
}

.control #play-pause-btn:hover {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.control #play-pause-btn i {
  color: #fff;
}

.control #prev-btn,
.control #next-btn {
  background-color: #888;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.control #prev-btn i,
.control #next-btn i {
  color: #333;
}

.control #prev-btn:hover,
.control #next-btn:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class="player">
  <section class="screen">
    <p id="song-name">No tracks found</p>
  </section>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <span id="progress" style="width: 0px"></span>
  </div>

  <section class="control">
    <button id="prev-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">skip_previous</i>
      </button>
    <button id="play-pause-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i>
      </button>
    <button id="next-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">skip_next</i>
      </button>
  </section>
</div>
```

En tu caso no necesitas sacar el elemento `audio` solo necesitas ocultarlo ya que estás creando el nodo de audio de él.